# How to know if iptables rules work?

Tags: linux, ip, smtp

I'm implementing a IP Rotation for my SMTP Server using iptables, how would I know it work? This is the rule I use.

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 80 -o eth0 -m statistic --mode nth --every 3 --packet 0 -j SNAT --to-source XXX.XXX.XXX.133
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 80 -o eth0 -m statistic --mode nth --every 3 --packet 0 -j SNAT --to-source XXX.XXX.XXX.134
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 80 -o eth0 -m statistic --mode nth --every 3 --packet 0 -j SNAT --to-source XXX.XXX.XXX.135
```

I tried email, and check the "**Show Original**" to check the header.

```
Received: from xxxxxxx.com (xxxxx.com. [xxx.xxx.xxx.133])
```

So, it is still the same. How long before the IP changes? I was in the impression that, every send of the mail, it will used a different IP based on the IP in my interfaces.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that?  It seems really counterintuitive, since establishing and maintaining a reputation for one IP address can be hard enough.  80 is also a really weird port to use for SMTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Linux, NAT is stateful and sticky.  It will continue to use the same outgoing IP/port pair assigned by SNAT (or MASQUERADE) for subsequent traffic between the same inside and outside host for an implementation-defined period.

I suggest also that there is no legitimate reason to do this.  Does your mother know what you're doing?  Either this is for spamming, or it's a really bad attempt at legitimate bulk mailing.  The best practice is to try and maintain a good reputation for one IP address per server; doing this is probably just going to triple your workload with no benefit.

Also, you've got the destination port on your iptables rules wrong; you're applying them to port 80, when you probably want 25 and 465.

Comment: Thank you sir. Yes actually i'm using it for bulk mailing. What would be the best approach on this? I'm using iRedMail for this and it's using port 587. so i should change the port 80 to 587 right? I'm using   this on a test server.

Comment: Not 80 at all.  587 is for submitting new messages, and if that's the port you're using, you'd need to apply the rule to it.  I have no idea where you got 80 from.

Comment: It was a copy paste. Silly me. I just tried to change it, but when I send 3 successive messages, the headers output still is the primary ip. Do i need to reboot the server for changes to apply?. I don't have  really much knowledge with IPTables and IP Rotation.